# How to pause & stop the mp3 url stream

Tags: android, streaming, media-player, mp3

i have build an app that mp3 playing from URL.The Problem is that the  pause ,stop & resume is not working properly. I tried all the code and viewed every pertinent question. but nothing works.so please give the solution for this, thankyou

```
import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
me 
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

public class MainActivity extends Activity  implements OnClickListener {
    private SeekBar mBar;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        findViewById(R.id.playOnline).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.playOnline2).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.pause).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button3).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.stop).setOnClickListener(this);
        mBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {


        case R.id.playOnline:
            PlayOnlineUrl();
            break;

        case R.id.playOnline2:
            PlayOnlineUrl2();
            break;
        case R.id.pause:
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                pause = true;
                mediaPlayer.pause();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.button3:
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                pause = false;
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.stop:
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer = null;
                timer.cancel();
                task.cancel();
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
       if( mediaPlayer.isPlaying() ) {
          mediaPlayer.stop();
       }
       finish();
    }  

    private void PlayOnlineUrl2() {
String url = "http://dj-videos.us/Music/XclusiveSinGleTrack/320%20Kbps/November%202013/Yo%20Yo%20Honey%20Singh%20-%20Blue%20Eyes-[DJKANG.Com].mp3"; // your URL here

        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
            }

        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        // You can show progress dialog here untill it prepared to play
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                // Now dismis progress dialog, Media palyer will start playing
                mp.start();
            }
        });
        mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                // dissmiss progress bar here. It will come here when
                // MediaPlayer
                // is not able to play file. You can show error message to user
                return false;
            }
        });
        }
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // Now dismis progress dialog, Media palyer will start playing
        mp.start();
        int duration = mp.getDuration();
        int period = duration / 1000;
        task = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                mBar.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (!pause) {
                            progresss++;
                            mBar.setProgress(progresss);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(task, 0, period * 10);

    }



private boolean pause = false;
int progresss = 0;
private TimerTask task;
private Timer timer = null;

    private void PlayOnlineUrl() {
        String url = "http://starmirchi.com/upload_file/Mp3%20Songs/3605/Yo!%20Yo!%20Honey%20Singh%20_%20Blue%20Eyes%20(DJ%20AKS%20Remix)-(StarMirchi.com).mp3"; // your URL here

        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
            }

        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        // You can show progress dialog here untill it prepared to play
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                // Now dismis progress dialog, Media palyer will start playing
                mp.start();
            }
        });
        mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                // dissmiss progress bar here. It will come here when
                // MediaPlayer
                // is not able to play file. You can show error message to user
                return false;
            }
        });
        }


}
```

THIS IS THE ERROR LOG

```
    01-15 23:27:18.257: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
    01-15 23:27:18.267: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
    01-15 23:27:18.267: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
    01-15 23:27:18.267: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
    01-15 23:27:18.267: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
    01-15 23:27:18.277: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
    01-15 23:27:18.277: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
    01-15 23:27:18.277: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
    01-15 23:27:18.277: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
    01-15 23:27:18.277: W/AudioService(381): onLoadSoundEffects(), Error -1 while loading samples
    01-15 23:27:18.367: E/AudioSink(52): received unknown event type: 1 inside CallbackWrapper !
    01-15 23:27:20.097: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
    01-15 23:27:20.097: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
    01-15 23:27:20.107: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
    01-15 23:27:20.107: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
    01-15 23:27:20.127: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
    01-15 23:27:20.127: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
    01-15 23:27:20.137: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
    01-15 23:27:20.137: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
    01-15 23:27:20.137: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
    01-15 23:27:20.197: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
    01-15 23:27:20.197: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
    01-15 23:27:20.207: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
    01-15 23:27:20.207: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
    01-15 23:27:20.207: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
    01-15 23:27:20.207: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
    01-15 23:27:20.207: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
    01-15 23:27:20.217: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
    01-15 23:27:20.217: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
    01-15 23:27:20.217: E/SoundPool(381): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
    01-15 23:27:20.217: W/AudioService(381): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
```

Comment: Your sound is playing or not.

Comment: sound is playing but pause , resume ,stop is not working

Comment: i got issue in your code and check my new update answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i am not wrong then you just replace this:

```
    findViewById(R.id.playOnline).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.playOnline2).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.pause).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button3).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.stop).setOnClickListener(this);
```

With below: globally defined all the buttons

```
Button Play1,Play2,Pause,button2,stop;
```

And add below into `OnCreate()`:

```
    Play1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.playOnline);
    Play2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.playOnline2);
    Pause=(Button)findViewById(R.id.pause);
    button2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    stop=(Button)findViewById(R.id.stop);

    Play1.setOnClickListener(this);
    Play2.setOnClickListener(this);
    Pause.setOnClickListener(this);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    stop.setOnClickListener(this);
```

And try out this.

**Update:**

Try your button listener on this way:

```
Play1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //Here your code
        }
    });
```

and for all the buttons.

Your code issue is here. You just defined your `MediaPlayer` object Globally then why r u created another `New MediaPlayer` Object into your `PlayOnlineUrl()` method. You Just add like below:

```
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
```

Comment: i tried out this but again pause ,resume & stop is not working. sp please give suggestion about pause,stop work properly, thank you

Comment: one problem is also coming once i pressed the play button then after again press the play button it started again